# Storing an "array" of data in mysql

Tags: cakephp

We have three models - Log, Kid, Volunteer.

Log hasmany Kid, Log hasmany Volunteer.

We want to be able to store, essentially, an array of strings of volunteer and kid names for each log....however, we are using cakephp and doing the standard relational database is not really an option right now.  Is there a way to do this?  We want users to be able to select multiple kids/volunteers from dropdown lists of kids and volunteers and then store these along with the log, maybe separated by a comma.

Comment: You've explained the problem (kind of) and you've even provided an answer (comma-separated values).  What is your actual question?

Comment: Maybe you should look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Why is standard relational database not an option?

Answer (score 0):

I see zero reasons why you could not use the database for that but ok... You can serialize your data in the beforeSave() method of the model and in the afterFind() callback you can deserialize it if the field is present.

This way you can store the array in a field and simply call serialize() and deserialize() on the data. No need to deal with comma separated values. There is the [Utils plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/utils) that contains a serializeable behavior that will automate that task for you.